# Broken Apache Virtual Hosts after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded to MAC OS X Yosemite and my apache configuration for my virtual hosts is not working. I upgraded php as suggested by @raoulsson ( https://superuser.com/questions/827937/apache-problems-after-upgrading-to-yosemite ):

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

And also edited /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName test.local
 DocumentRoot "/Users/my-name/www/test"

 <Directory "/Users/my-name/www/test>
     AllowOverride All
     #Order allow,deny
     #Allow from all
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
 </Directory>

 <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
 </IfModule>

 <Files ".ht*">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
 </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now navigating to one of my virtual hosts (http://test.local) gives me the message **"It Works"** instead of showing my website. Anyone with an idea on what I'm missing?

**EDIT:**
So it turns out that the issue was in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. I had to re-enable virtual hosts in order for it to work. And since I'm using rewrites in the above virtual host, I also had to load the rewrite engine.

```
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Not sure if the alias_module is necessary, but my configuration is now working, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at first, you need to remove the “#” in some lines. espacially the vhost.conf file is not imported by default.

like :

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

to

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and add some '#' in others

```
<Directory />
     AllowOverride none
     Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
     #AllowOverride none
     #Require all denied
</Directory>
```

according to http://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/

Comment: thanks, you just saved me an hour of faffing around :)

Answer (score 3):

OS X 10.10 Yosemite comes with Apache 2.4 instead of Apache 2.2 in Mavericks.
The major difference in configuration is that you have to replace...

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

...with...

```
Require all granted
```

See Apache doc's manual [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) for more details.

**UPDATE:**
Please be aware that after upgrading OS X you will usually find your old config files as backups next to the new ones written by Yosemite. They are labeled e.g. *httpd.conf.pre-update* and/or *httpd.conf~previous* and can be found in the same paths as the new configs (e.g. in */private/etc/apache2*).

Comment: thanks for the note about the pre-update, didn't know that :)